# change apps name in django admin

Tags: django, admin

How do I change a Django app's name in the admin?

I'm using Django 1.6.10

I've tried this:-

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
        pass
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'My APP name'
```

but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you upgrade to the latest 1.7.X, or ideally, Django 1.8.X. Django 1.6 is end of life, and does not support security updates.

The `app_label` should be a package name, e.g. `myapp`. It is not meant to be used as a human friendly string e.g. 'My App'. Doing this might break things.

The Django app loading was refactored in Django 1.7. In Django 1.7+, you can change the displayed application name by setting [`verbose_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.verbose_name) for your app config. I'm afraid I don't know of a way to change the display of the app name for Django < 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

write this code at the bottom of `urls.py`

```
admin.site.site_header = 'My APP name'
```

Comment: i got this error  NameError: name 'admin' is not defined

Comment: that's because you haven't defined the django admin yet @IamMoon

Comment: @IamMoon Have you Added `django.contrib.admin` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: Yes.. i have added in my setting

Comment: Have you imported it?